# Should I worry about my cat chewing scissor handles?

Tags: cats, eating, dental-care

Ginger has recently started chewing on scissor handles. It is a recent habit because the scissors used to be scattered about in random places and I recently collected them into a holding container (so the change is that now the scissor handles are available). She apparently has no interest in scissors that lay flat on a table.

[image]

Usually I look at a cat's mouth when they chew on random objects, and her gums are slightly inflamed around the gum line, but not more than normal for her. She had a dental in June because of a plaque build up.

She doesn't chew on any other weird things that I've noticed, but she does like to lick tape and cloth covered speakers.

Should I be concerned about this habit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention if they're usually the same pair she goes for, but the shape of the handles and the upright position may be a factor in relief. In any event, I think some small amount concern is warranted since many tooth and gum issues are not directly visible and so it may be that she is experiencing discomfort that is alleviated by the activity (similar to baby teething relief).

Another way to check on this is try rubbing her jaw a bit and see if she leans into it much more directly than you would expect. One of our cats definitely has issues below the gum line and responds with clear relief when we rub her jaw area. She leans into this very hard, much more so than other types of petting. Unfortunately, because of a heart condition, they can't put her under to fix it.

It could be nothing, though, just a odd behavior, but only a vet can really confirm that.

Comment: She doesn't seem to really lean into it, and she's on a pain killer for arthritis already. I'll ask the vet about it.

Comment: @Zaralynda - yeah, it may be because she likes how it feels. Cats are weird. :)